# Preserve Current Tab View page number in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have two tabs which contain two separate tables with separate pagination.
Both are using different query param to represent the page number.

```
http://localhost:8000/additionalfee/view?page=2
http://localhost:8000/additionalfee/view?serve=2
```

When I clicked pagination for one tab, I losing the page number for another tab. it will reset to 1.

I was trying to append query param when I clicked on any tab but I am unable to manipulate `{!! $serves -> render() !!}` && `{!! $fees -> render() !!}` render method.

Is there any way I can preserve the state of another pagination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this using the `appends` method on the pagination object.

For example, in your controller:

```php
Fees::paginate(20)->appends(request()->except('page'));
```

When laravel is generating the links, it will include your existing query params.

Documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/pagination#displaying-pagination-results